# Iterate over dom elements using document.getElementsByTagName, pass element as jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-traversal

What I need is to iterate over the dom at some start element and then go through all elements below the start element.

Here is what I was doing so far.

```
function iterDomFromStartElem = function(startElem, callBackFunc) {
    if (startElem !== null) {
        var items = startElem.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            callBackFunc(items[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The reason why I need to iterate over the dom from some start element is because our team recently got a request to implement font resizing; however, we developed are site statically with font-size in many different places using pixels. I realize that the easier approach would be to refactor the existing code, set a static font size at the root of the page, and use em's/percentages else where, so that if the business owner wanted to have a resize control on the pages, all we would have to do is increase the font-size in one spot. This refactor would require many hours, and i have been tasked with this using the least amount of man hours.

So, then, I have a call back defined like so,

```
function resizeFont(startElem, scale) {
    iterDomFromStartElem(startElem, function(node) {
        // get current size of node, apply scale, increase font size
    }
}
```

Using this raw javascript would work but i'm having trouble getting font-size if its declared inside a css class.

I know that jquery has a css property and if I had a jquery object I could do $(this).css(....), so,

when I call callBackFunc(items[i]), how can I convert the items[i] into a jquery object so that in my call back function, I can do node.css(......)?

I guess I could do $(items[i].id), perhaps that would be the simplest.

Is there an easier way with javascript to determine the font size even if that font size is declared in a css class and that css class is attached to the element?

Comment: You could add css with !important to similar sizes to override the default settings. But it would almost seem easier to write a php script to edit the actual css files then do it with javascript.  Why make the user's browser do this kind of work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preface: I think you're better off fixing the problem properly. You might save an hour or two now by taking a shortcut, but it's likely to cost you in the long term.

But re your actual question:

> how can I convert the items[i] into a jquery object so that in my call back function, I can do node.css(......)?

If you pass a raw DOM object into [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), jQuery will return a wrapper around it. You don't have to go via the ID.

You can also get a jQuery instance for **all** descendant elements of a given starting point, like this:

```
var x = $("#starting_point *");
```

...although you'd still end up creating a lot of temporary objects if you then looped through it, like this:

```
$("#starting_point *").each(function() {
    // Here, `this` is the raw DOM element
});
```

Here's an example of looping all elements under a given starting point with jQuery, in this case showing their tag and `id` (if any) and turning them blue ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/afurus)):

```
$("#start *").each(function() {
  display(this.tagName + "#" + (this.id || "?"));
  $(this).css("color", "blue");
});
```

Note I said **under**. If you also want to include `#start`, the selector changes to `#start, #start *`.

Here's a complete example of increasing the font size of elements starting with (and including) a given start point, where the font size is variously set by inline and stylesheet styles ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/afurus/2)):

CSS:

```
.x13 {
  font-size: 13px;
}
.x17 {
  font-size: 17px;
}
.x20 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="btnBigger" value="Bigger">
<div id="start" class="x13">
  This is in 13px
  <p style="font-size: 15px">This is in 15px
    <span class="x17">and this is 17px</span></p>
  <ul>
    <li id="the_list_item" style="10px">10px
      <strong style="font-size: 8px">8px
        <em class="x20">five</em>
      </strong>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $("#btnBigger").click(function() {
    $("#start, #start *").each(function() {
      var $this = $(this),
          fontSize = parseInt($this.css("font-size"), 10);
      display("fontSize = " + fontSize);
      $this.css("font-size", (fontSize + 2) + "px");
    });
  });

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }

});
```

Comment: Yep, I agree, fixing the problem now properly would be much better.