# Determine effective z-index (vertical stack position) of each element in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, z-index

I'm writing a tool that uses javascript to do something like convert an HTML document into SVG.

That requires knowing which elements could overlap other elements, and thus the overall z-index stacking order of the entire document.

So I want to assign each element in the source page a number such that if I rearranged all the elements to overlap one another, the number would reflect their position in that stack, with 1 being the top (or bottom), 2 being the next, etc.

This is of course influenced by z-index values but is not directly related to them.

I know there's a way to do this myself using careful DOM traversal and sorting, but it would be tricky.

Is there an existing approach that's easier?

I can use any necessary library, though understanding how to do it in vanillaJS would be helpful.

Thanks!

Edit: as I look into rolling my own, the CSS entry on painting order is at https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html, with a healthy discussion at http://vanseodesign.com/css/css-stack-z-index/

Comment: One crazy thought I had was to actually manipulate the elements so they *do* overlap, then trigger a click event and watch how it bubbles through them, but it's not trivial to make sure they all overlap without altering their relative z-index.  I'd certainly entertain any suggestions like that, though.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do, why do you need this info?

Comment: I'm trying to convert the HTML into different HTML structured such that each element is generally positioned absolutely and separately from the others, as in an SVG or PSD document.  This is to permit importing any HTML into an HTML-based prototyping tool.  It may be easiest to think of it as converting HTML into SVG and then back into HTML.  Which actually isn't a crazy thought but seems a little excessive and would add its own problems.

Comment: The problem as you've described it is not solvable, you cannot emulate hiding overflow, for example, using only standalone absolutely positioned elements.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying.  Obviously this is a solved problem, every web browser on the planet properly determines the visual stacking order of elements.  Clearly there are cases that won't translate properly and that's fine.  I'm just wondering if anybody knows of code to determine the relative stacking order within javascript.  I'm currently taking a look at open source browsers but that can be a lot of code to wade through.

Comment: This question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/18106571/215552. Note [this great comment by Bergi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106571/how-to-characterize-z-indexing-for-the-dom-2?rq=1#comment26511649_18106571): z-index values are relative to the closest positioned element. Thus, even if you did getComputedStyle, it wouldn't be correct. Also, you may want to amend your question to remove the request for external libraries, as that is explicitly off-topic according to the [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Tempting, but that just returns the actual property value of z-index, not the calculated position in the painting stack.  So it returns a lot of "auto" and "3" and such values.  Goes back to having to determine each stacking context and then sort by stacking order, determined based on the CSS painting order specification.  Thank you for suggestion though.

Comment: This answer gets you a large part of the way there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822667/iterate-over-dom-elements-using-document-getelementsbytagname-pass-element-as-j

Comment: Another clever thing to consider - you could just look for things with `position: relative` and `position: absolute` - everything else should be sitting on the same plane.

Comment: Thanks, folks.  I got something working courtesy of the8472's advice below.  I've released the code and an overview to https://github.com/JBlitzen/determine-stacking-order, use at your own risk!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested idea:

1. Massage the entire DOM tree with CSS `transform: translate()` styles until *all* visible elements are stacked in a way that their bounding boxes overlap at a particular point, e.g. at the top left corner of the document.
2. obtain the top-most element with document `document.elementFromPoint`
3. style the element with `pointer-events:none;`, this excludes it from the element retrieval
4. goto 2

That should give you the total ordering.

Comment: Nice, I hadn't considered translate and didn't know about elementFromPoint.  Going to try this.  Thanks!

Comment: That might be the winner.  I need to be careful setting the transforms since transforming a parent will naturally move the children as well, so I have to transform the roots, then recurse into their children, transform those, then recurse into their children, etc.  I also need to break out  of recursion for svg elements at least, maybe others.  But extremely promising so far and I think I can make it work.  Thanks!

Comment: You nailed it.  Works pretty damn well!  I've uploaded the code to https://github.com/JBlitzen/determine-stacking-order and will continue to test it, but right now with current test data it's doing EXACTLY what I want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Well, honestly, this is a hard one to answer you say:

> This is of course influenced by z-index values but is not directly related to them.

But, if I simply answer the question in the title:

> Determine effective z-index (vertical stack position) of each element in the DOM?

If you know the id (or name) of the elements then it is relatively easy to get the zIndex as you can get the z-index of any dom element with:

```
document.getElementById('someID').style.zIndex;
```

For any additional answers, you will need to narrow down your requirements.

Comment: That has the same problem as above; the "z-index" CSS property of a given element is not the effective z-index in the painting order of the page.  It's clearly considered in a number of spots in the painting order algorithm, but I'm talking about actual z-index painting order that the z-index CSS property is used in calculating.  Consider https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html